# Converting multiple rasters to new raster (mosaic) in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, mosaic

I want to use **[Mosaic To New Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000)** in ModelBuilder.

I want it to give me multiple outputs because I have multiple folders with a different number of images in each.

Below is the model that I have already tried.

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OAywb.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two models, a main model and a sub model. The main model iterates through your folders, calls the sub model - which collects all the rasters within the current folder and passes the results back to the main model and into the mosaic to new raster tool.

- **Main Model** - selects a folder and passes it to the sub model. Mosaics rasters from sub model.

[image]

- **Sub Model** - collects rasters within folder and pass them back up.
  [image]